# Remove "constant" values from each time window in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, nested-loops

I want to check whether values in a column are constant or have little variation(<1) at a location **for a certain duration** (referred to as "constant phenomenon"). If so, I want to identify and remove the last row (with the latest timestamp) that contributes to the "constant phenomenon". This is because removing this row will keep the constant duration under the given threshold.

An set of input and output example is like below:

Input:

```
     LOCATION           DATE_TIME  random  value
0        111 2016-01-01 00:45:00       2      1
1        111 2016-01-01 12:15:00       9      9
2        111 2016-01-01 12:30:00       6      9
3        111 2016-01-01 12:45:00       3      9
4        111 2016-01-01 13:00:00       6      9
5        222 2016-01-01 12:00:00       3      9
6        222 2016-01-01 12:15:00       3      4
7        222 2016-01-01 12:30:00       5      5
8        333 2016-01-01 12:00:00       9      5
9        333 2016-01-01 12:15:00       2      5
10       333 2016-01-01 12:30:00       6      5
11       333 2016-01-02 12:30:00       8      5
12       444 2016-01-01 12:00:00       4      5
```

Output (Original row 3, 4, 10, 11 are removed):

```
    LOCATION           DATE_TIME  random  value
0       111 2016-01-01 00:45:00       1      1
1       111 2016-01-01 12:15:00       7      9
2       111 2016-01-01 12:30:00       1      9
3       222 2016-01-01 12:00:00       8      9
4       222 2016-01-01 12:15:00       1      4
5       222 2016-01-01 12:30:00       9      5
6       333 2016-01-01 12:00:00       1      5
7       333 2016-01-01 12:15:00       1      5
8       444 2016-01-01 12:00:00       6      5
```

ADDED EXPLANATION TO THE EXAMPLE:

The reason why original row 3 is removed is because the value are "constant" from 12:15:00-12:45:00, which reaches the threshold of 30min. By removing it, the time window starting with 12:15:00 are all clear. However, the next time window starting with 12:30:00 encountered the same issue due to row 4, i.e. constant value again lasting for 30min. Therefore, row 4 is removed.

A few other things to note: 1) the values are not at a fixed time interval; 2) the cells under 'value' and 'random' can be integer or float. 3) once identified, the row that contributes to the "constant phenomenon" will be removed immediately, i.e. reflected in the next round of checking.

I have a working code as shown below that checks within each time window, but it seems to be very exhaustive and time-consuming.

I feel like it could be done much faster, e.g. using generators instead of iterators or using a recursive function, but I am not sure how to code it.

Thank you for your time.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import datetime

        
def check_duration(df_all, measure, maxd):
    
    link_group = df_all.groupby('LOCATION', as_index = False)
    
    df_all_cleansed = pd.DataFrame()
    df_remove = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for k in link_group.groups:
        df_link = link_group.get_group(k)
        df_link = df_link.sort_values(['DATE_TIME'])
        df_link.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
        # Until which row is the check necessary 
        num_check = len(df_link.loc[df_link['DATE_TIME'] <= max(df_link['DATE_TIME'])-maxd])
        i=0
        
        while i < num_check:
            start = df_link['DATE_TIME'].iloc[i]
            end = start+maxd
            if len(df_link.loc[df_link['DATE_TIME']>=end]) == 0:
                break
            else:
                # A time window with duration maxd as the base
                df_target = df_link.loc[(df_link['DATE_TIME'] < end)&(df_link['DATE_TIME'] >= start)] 
                # The critical row that may or may not be removed depending on the below if statement
                df_critical = df_link.loc[[df_link.loc[df_link['DATE_TIME']>=end, 'DATE_TIME'].idxmin()]] 

                df_appended = df_critical.append(df_target)
                
                # Check within this window, whether 1) there is more than one data and 2) the max-min 
                if len(df_appended)>1 and (max(df_appended[measure])-min(df_appended[measure]))<1:
                    that_time = df_critical['DATE_TIME'].iloc[0]
                    print('Removed timestamp: ', that_time)
                    that_index_list = df_link[df_link['DATE_TIME'] == that_time].index.tolist()
                    # Just a precautionary step in case of duplicated date_time (very unlikely)
                    if len(that_index_list)==1:
                        that_index = that_index_list[0]
                    else: 
                        print('Duplicated date_time!!!')
                        sys.exit(0)
                    df_link.drop(that_index,inplace=True)
                    df_remove = df_remove.append(df_critical)
                    df_link.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    
                else:
                    i += 1
        df_all_cleansed = df_all_cleansed.append(df_link)
    
    df_all_cleansed.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    return df_all_cleansed, df_remove

d = {'LOCATION':[111,111,111,111,111,222,222,222,333,333,333,333,444],
     'DATE_TIME': ['2016-01-01 00:45:00', '2016-01-01 12:15:00',
       '2016-01-01 12:30:00', '2016-01-01 12:45:00', '2016-01-01 13:00:00',
       '2016-01-01 12:00:00', '2016-01-01 12:15:00', '2016-01-01 12:30:00',
       '2016-01-01 12:00:00', '2016-01-01 12:15:00','2016-01-01 12:30:00',
       '2016-01-02 12:30:00', '2016-01-01 12:00:00'], 
     'random': [random.randint(0, 9) for p in range(13)],
     'value': [1,9,9,9,9,9,4,5,5,5,5,5,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'])
print('******************* BEFORE: *******************\n', df)

threshold_duration = datetime.timedelta(days=0, hours=0, minutes=30, seconds=0)
df, df_remove = check_duration(df,'value',threshold_duration)
print('******************* AFTER: *******************\n', df)
```

Comment: "the values are not at a fixed time interval;" Do the timestamps actually matter to the solution, then? If so, how? Also, I don't understand why, in your example, rows 3 and 4 are both removed, but row 2 isn't.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hi Karl, the timestamps do matter as it is the duration of "constant" values (variation<1 actually) that decides whether or not to remove the last row. The reason why row 2 is not removed is because adding it only makes the "constant" duration to be 15min, which does not exceed the ```threshold_duration``` of 30 minutes. Please let me know if anything else is unclear. Thanks.

Comment: Does https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html help?